# Backtracking Recursion through a List of Strings

Tags: java, string, list, recursion, iterator

I'm trying to write a method that returns a sub lists and each containin the max value of strigns from a larger list.

I'm using iterator and backtrack recursion to achieve this, however - I'm not familiar with backtrack recursion. Any suggestions on how to make this work. Or if my code needs adjustments?

This is what I have so far:

```
private void printAnagrams(List<String> anagrams, int max, List<List<String>> listofLists) {
    Iterator<String> iterate = anagrams.iterator();
    String word = "";
    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < anagrams.size(); i++) {
            word = iterate.next();
            listofLists.add(new ArrayList<>());
            listofLists.get(i).add(word);
            if (listofLists.size() == max) {
                listofLists.add(new ArrayList<>());
                    // Continue new list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method that calls the private method:

```
 public void printAnagrams(String phrase, int max, List<List<String>> anagrams) {
    if (anagrams == null || max < 0) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
    } else if (max == 0) {
        getWords(phrase);
    } else  
        printAnagrams(phrase, max, anagrams);
}// End of printAnagram method
```

Sample output:

List:

```
[core, course, cs, cure, for, force, forces, four, of, off, offer, offers, or, our, ours, re, score, so, source, suffer, sure, us, use, user]
```

SubLists with max = 3:

```
[core, off, us]
[core, us, off]
[course, off]
[cure, off, so]
[cure, so, off]
[force, of, us]
[force, us, of]
```

Comment: Don't use raw types, e.g. `Iterator`, `List`. Use `Iterator<String>`, `List<String>` etc.

Comment: Also, `list = (Set<String>) getWords(phrase);`: aside from the confusing naming ("list is a set" doesn't make sense), you are overwriting the parameter `list` - why pass that parameter at all?

Comment: @AndyTurner - You're right, I just made those changes. I guess I'm still trying to narrows what I have to do exactly. I have refined the question, and I guess I need to figure out how to make this a List of List? I just updated the question.

Comment: Can you include sample input and output so your intent is a bit clearer?

Comment: @shmosel - Yes, I just made the changes.